# Unable to delete zip folders older than 14 days

Tags: powershell

I am unable to delete zip folders older than 14 days from a directory. The rest of my script works fine, however the following code block is failing:

It has not thrown any errors, the path has been sanity checked, however, I placed old documents in to see if they are cleared up to no avail. It prints the statement that the folder path exists however does not delete anything from the folder.

```
if (!(Test-Path $folderpath)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $folderpath
    Write-Host "$folderpath created"
} else {
    Write-Host "$folderpath already exists, will remove old items"
    $HowOld = -14
    Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse |
        where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($HowOld) -and -not $_.PSIsContainer} |
        % {Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -WhatIf}
}
```

Here is the full script for completeness:

```
#Get backup folder drive letter
$letter = [System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives() | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 'Fixed' -and $_.Name -notlike '*C*'} | Select-Object  -Property Name
[string] $drive =  "$letter"
$Drive2 = $null
$Drive2 = $drive.Substring($drive.IndexOf('=')+1)
$BackupDrive = $Drive2.Substring(0, $Drive2.IndexOf('}'))

#Check the programname log path.
$logspath = "C:\ProgramData\programname\programname4.0\Logs" 
If (!(test-path $logspath))
{

  $IQlogspath = "C:\ProgramData\programname\iQSonar4.0\Logs"
  }
Else
{
$IQlogspath = "C:\ProgramData\programname\programname4.0\Logs" 
}


#check if backup folder exists, clean if exists and if not create it.
$folderpath = $BackupDrive + "programname_logs"

If(!(test-path $folderpath))
{
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $folderpath
write-host "$folderpath created"
}

Else
{
write-host "$folderpath already exists, will remove old items"
$HowOld = -14
get-childitem $Path -recurse | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays($HowOld) -and -not $_.psiscontainer} |% {remove-item $_.fullname -force -whatif}
}

#check if todays folder exists, if not create it
$todaysdate = (Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
$todaysbackup = $folderpath + "\Logs_Backup_" + $todaysdate
$todaysbackupzip = $todaysbackup + ".zip"

If(!(test-path $todaysbackup))
{
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $todaysbackup
write-host  "$todaysbackup created, now moving items"

#select and move files to backup folder
get-childitem -Path $IQlogspath | 
    where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-7) -and $_.Name -notmatch "Service"} | 
    move-item -destination $todaysbackup
Start-Sleep -s 10

write-host "checking for zip"
If(Test-path $todaysbackupzip) {
write-host "$todaysbackupzip already exists, changing name"
$todaysbackupzip = $null
$todaysbackupzip = $folderpath + "\Logs_Backup_" + $todaysdate + ".re-run" + ".zip"
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($todaysbackup, $todaysbackupzip)
write-host  "$todaysbackupzip created"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $todaysbackup
write-host  "$todaysbackup removed"
exit
}
write-host  "creating zip folder, $todaysbackupzip"
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($todaysbackup, $todaysbackupzip)
write-host  "$todaysbackupzip created"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $todaysbackup
write-host  "$todaysbackup removed"
exit
}

Else
{
write-host "$todaysbackup already exists, attempting to zip"

#check if zip backup folder already exists
If(Test-path $todaysbackupzip) {
write-host "$todaysbackupzip already exists, changing name"
$todaysbackupzip = $null
$todaysbackupzip = $folderpath + "\Logs_Backup_" + $todaysdate + ".re-run" + ".zip"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($todaysbackup, $todaysbackupzip)
write-host  "$todaysbackupzip created"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $todaysbackup
write-host  "$todaysbackup removed"
exit
}

Else
{
Start-Sleep -s 10
write-host  "creating zip folder, $todaysbackupzip"

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($todaysbackup, $todaysbackupzip)
write-host  "$todaysbackupzip created"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $todaysbackup
write-host  "$todaysbackup removed"
exit
}
}

#Get OS disk label
$OSDisk = Get-WmiObject  Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object WindowsDirectory
[string] $drive =  "$OSDisk"
$Drive2 = $null
$Drive2 = $drive.Substring($drive.IndexOf('=')+1)

$OSDrive = $Drive2.Substring(0, $Drive2.IndexOf('\'))
$OSDrive2 = "'$OSDrive'"
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk  -Filter "DeviceID=$OSDrive2"| Select-Object FreeSpace
[INT] $FreeSpace = $disk.FreeSpace /1GB

If ($FreeSpace -gt 5) {
write-host "no additional backup requirement, exiting script"
exit
}

Else {
write-host "Running one off clear"
$OneOff = $IQlogspath + "\Logs_One_Off_" + $todaysdate
$OneOffZip = $OneOff + ".zip"
If(!(test-path $OneOff))
{
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $OneOff
write-host  "$OneOff created"
}
Else {
write-host "folder already exists"
}
#select and move files to backup folder
write-host "moving logs to $OneOff"
get-childitem -Path $IQlogspath | 
    where-object {$_.Name -notmatch "Service"} | 
    move-item -destination $OneOff
Start-Sleep -s 10
write-host  "creating zip folder, $todaysbackupzip"

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($OneOff, $OneOffZip)
write-host  "$todaysbackupzip created"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $todaysbackup
write-host  "$todaysbackup removed"
exit
}
```

Comment: `i placed old documents in to see if they are cleared up` - Did you do this more than 14 days ago?

Comment: Remove `-WhatIf`, so that `Remove-Item` actually deletes things instead of telling you what it would delete?

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
@acro444 No i moved files with a date modified time of 14 days, i take it that would update the last write time?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers orry i failed to mention I have removed the whatif during testing. The whatif does not output any candidates for deletion, just put it back in for now for safety.

Comment: You need to change attributes (Created, Modified, Accessed) of the file to make it old. If you copy/move file, the created/modified date changes to the current.